# Applying actions on selectors in every client and tab through jQuery

Tags: jquery, tabs, selector

I want to make changes in all client browsers with jQuery.

Example:

```
$(#event).change(function(){
   $('.selector').html(value);
});
```

Can I apply this action automatically in every client browser and every tab (to appear immediately when event occurs)?

Similar to Facebook comments?

Comment: If no syntax error, why couldn't you?

Comment: I can update just on the same window.. but I want to update on all windows opened just similar to facebook comments